# Spring MVC - get address from request

Tags: http, spring-mvc, controller

This is my case, set by step:

1. Run below page under address:

localhost:8080/user/data/expenses

2. On this page click link

localhost:8080/user/data/change_button/9_2015

3. Now my controller is started:

[image: Screenshot]

My question:
How can I get information from what side was call my controller. I need exactly this information which is strong below:

localhost:8080 **/user/data/expenses**

M-Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infact there is way to get the referer of the request as it is part of the HTTP header. Just inject `HttpServletRequest` to the mapped method then get the header named "referer".

`request.getHeader("referer");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `HttpServletRequest` and then use [`getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) to get the data. Read the javadoc for `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: When I use getRequestURI() received /user/data/change_button/9_2015 not /user/data/expenses .